Is there a way to open Windows Mobile Device Center folders in python?
I work with a warehouse that uses old ScanCountPro devices, and to connect to them, I need to use Windows Mobile Device Center.  This is not an issue, but I want to automate a process using python, and I need to copy files from the device, to my local machine.  Problem is, the directory that the files are in is not easily accessible in python.
Here are my steps:

I get the directory from windows explorer
I attempt to locate files in this directory in python.

open("This PC//CK3X177F1891347//Flash File Store") 

Get an error.

File "/mnt/c/Users/USER/Documents/test.py", line 2, in <module> open("This PC\CK3X177F1891347\Flash File Store") FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'This PC\\CK3X177F1891347\\Flash File Store'
Is there any way to get the files from this folder?

The folder CK3X177F1891347 from screenshot doesn't looks like a regular file-systems folder or druve. Most likely it is provided by an Explorer plugin, which means there is no drive letter or other way to access it outside of explorer.exe and thus also not by Python.

It is long time I worked with ActiveSync connected PocketPC devices. Here is a python way I found: https://devcodef1.com/news/1414819/windows-mobile-device-center-with-python

@josef I looked into that, however it appears it is out of date.
In the example, it uses the line: devices = [dev for dev in pywinusb.devices if dev.product_id == 0x2311]
However, pywinusb has no declaration of devices.

You should ask the author of the article if there is soemthing wrong with the code. You can also copy files automatically from/to device without any programming: https://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/02/26/pc-activesync-can-be-used-to-automate-tasks-on-device-connection/ you need to have the remote tools (itsutils) installed: https://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/02/26/pocketpc-and-windowsce-essential-tools/#more-345
